# Can you get poisoned too by kissing a poisoned person/having sex with them?

Tags: plot

The MC (a dragon in human form) gets poisoned by drinking poisoned tea. Then hours later the MC kisses a human, who also gives him a blowjob and doesn't spit it out. Can that other person get poisoned too by kissing the MC and giving him a blowjob?

Comment: I believe allergens can work this way, but whether poisons work the same way, I don't know.

Comment: Please don't deface your questions by redacting them after they've already been answered. It's impolite to the users who put the effort in to answer your question. I can see that you're unhappy with the answers you've received, but you can always edit your question to provide *additional* detail to clarify what you want. There's no need to tear the whole thing down.

Comment: Re: close votes. (1) "Opinion-based: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers." The question clearly asks for facts ("Can that other person get poisoned ... ?") and I have given an answer that cites scientific sources. This close reason therefore does not apply. (2) "Needs details or clarity: This question should include more details and clarify the problem." It seems quite clear to me what question OP has and how it could be answered (see 1). This close reason therefore also does not apply.

Comment: @Ben Check revision history. The asker repeatedly made big changes to the question after it was answered. At one point, its entirety read "can you get poisoned" (sic); at another, all it contained was the word "delete" repeated 15 times. The mods eventually restored a sensible question (half of which the asker never put in the question but only in the comments replying to answers). I'm still not retreating my close vote even if it doesn't apply to the current state of the question because if I did that, I couldn't cast it again if the question got edited badly once more.

Comment: @Divizna Well, OP has deleted their account (they marked it for deletion at the same time they started defacing it), so we shouldn't have to worry about that anymore.

Comment: If the poison (or the dragon) is highly radioactive, the human might have a problem.  Not so much from ingesting the poison but from an extended term of exposure.

Comment: @HenryTaylor I'd think that a dragon full of something radioactive in his bodily fluids should have a problem as well! (See below for a very rough comparison of orders of magnitude.)

Answer (score 2):

I seriously doubt it. If the first person had such a high concentration of the poison in their body that it could harm the second person, then I very much think the first person would already be dead at ingestion.

Infections, yes. Allergens, not excluding (if only the second person is allergic). Poisons, no.

You dilute - let's be generous, half a litre poisoned tea in a sixty-kilo body (while not even all poison is absorbed in the body). That drops the poison concentration by 120 as the lower limit. Two orders of magnitude. And then the second person ingests - how much of that extremely duiluted liquid? Not a lot. Saliva transfer in a kiss is only traces; semen volume in ejaculation, as I'm finding out, is on average less than 5 ml. Even if the first character were badly poisoned (and be real, someone in such state is not in the mood for sexy fun), your second character wouldn't be likely to get even slightly sick.

Comment: Think of the dose. Your dragon is probably downright immune to the poison in question. But anyway, figure out how much of the poison the human character must ingest, and what it says about the total amount of the poison in the dragon's body. 70 mg arsenic in 5 ml semen means 840 g arsenic in 60 kg body means not something you can not notice has been added to your 0.5 l = 0.5 kg pot of tea.

Comment: @Divizna But then the immune person might intentionally "poison" themselves to poison someone with a kiss or through sex.

Comment: @Ben But why go to such lengths when you can apply the poison topically on your body's surface instead? (Was the plot of a mystery series episode I saw. Not even dragons involved.)

Comment: Maybe it's a kink (for the dragon or OP)? I mean, I guess OP is not writing a hard science novel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be possible.

Poison is present in [semen](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2774220/) and [saliva](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/7387392/) in similar amounts as in the rest of the body.

If the person ingesting the poison is immune to the poison, they could thus poison someone using their bodily fluids.